# How to host an ASP.Net Core Server in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an older WinForms application which has been successfully ported from .Net 3.5 to .Net 5.

Now I would like to add a web interface to the application using ASP.Net Core. And to keep the overview I would like to outsource the functionality in a class library.

So I have created a class library and this uses as project SDK `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. Additionally I added the following references in the `.csproj`:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectCapability Include="AspNetCore" />
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

With this, I was able to compile a small startup class without any errors, as all references to ASP.Net Core seem to be to it. However, when I try to run it, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'` exception.
Currently my startup code looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Any Ideas, what I'm doing wrong here? Or is my plan even impossible?

Comment: Why do you want the added complexity that ASP.NET Core brings?

Comment: Super easy for Blazor Desktop, https://github.com/edandersen/blazor-desktop-crossplatform-sample/tree/master/src/BlazorWinFormsApp

Comment: Blazor Desktop is not exactly what I am looking for. As I said, I want to add to the application the function that from a remote computer via web browser certain data can be retrieved and functions can be called. Blazor Desktop uses <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor. If I use these in my project, I get the known error message with the latter and with the former I get the error that my class library has no static main method

Comment: A class library doesn't need a main method because it's not an entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Moving most of your logic out to a classlib is a great idea.

WebApplication.CreateBuilder() must be run in a project with the Sdk of "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web".

This is set in the  element of your .csproj.

I'd recommend moving as much as you can over to a classlib and keeping only what can't be moved in the ASP.NET project.

---

The .csproj file of an ASP.NET project starts with this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

And the .csproj file of a classlib starts with this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Comment: The Problem is, that I have to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` as the SDK for my main application to get the winforms running...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to separate business logic into ASP.NET Core Web API project.

Then both WinForms and web interface can just call the same API.